# How do I click on an anchor tag once its href gets set, after a delay?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

There's a page whose anchor tag becomes clickable after a delay. I want to use a userscript to click it once it's clickable.

On page load, the HTML source is:

```
<div id="buton" style="display:none">
  <div class="info-link right">
    <a href="#">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

After a delay, the `#button` becomes visible, and the HTML becomes:

```
<div id="buton" style="">
  <div class="info-link right">
    <a href="http://178.32.87.115/jetapi/mali.php?go=aHR0cHM6Ly9vdXJsLmlvLzZpN0Mw" data-ss1536034362="1">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using this code to click it [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzk3pv81/), and it ran successfully:

```
document.querySelector('.info-link.right a').click()
```

However, when I tried it on the actual [website here](http://178.32.87.115/jetapi/?file=28941536032773) (using tampermonkey), nothing happens. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the element's `href` gets reassigned before clicking it. Luckily, your site in question is static, and the `<a>` is in the HTML on pageload, so it can be selected immediately - then, you can observe it with `MutationObserver` so that once its `href` gets changed, you can `click()` on it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         clickit
// @namespace    CertainPerformance
// @version      1
// @match        http://178.32.87.115/jetapi/?file=28941536032773
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const a = document.querySelector('.info-link > a');

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  a.click();
});
observer.observe(a, { attributes: true });
```

Note that if the site *wasn't* static, and the `<a>` didn't exist on page load, you would have to do something else, perhaps use `setInterval` and continuously check the page for an `a` whose `href` matches what you want:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const a = document.querySelector('a[href^="http://178.32.87.115/jetapi/mali.php?go="]');
  if (a) a.click();
}, 50);
```

Comment: Actually, @GregorIsack, this fails if `.info-link > a` does not already exist

Comment: @BrockAdams Unless the HTML changes, it will exist: view-source:http://178.32.87.115/jetapi/?file=28941536032773

Comment: @CertainPerformance, if the page is ajax driven, or the script runs at document-start, the node will not necessarily exist, in the general case.  That one web site might be static (for now), and the script not run at start (for now), but this is brittle "time bomb" coding.

Comment: @BrockAdams Aren't userscripts, nearly by definition, brittle like that? When the page changes, often one *will* have to change around some userscript code. I suppose one could use something like `setInterval` and continuously examine the `<a>`s on a page, but that seems inelegant and needlessly complicated for a problem that may well never exist.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, this code is not just brittle against site design changes, it does not work for the OP's stated problem of a button/link that "appears using javascript".  It only works for static pages, or in occasional flukes whereby you win a race condition.  It is overkill in both of those.  Using set `setInterval` *is* an extremely robust, flexible, and proven way to solve the AJAX problem, but `MutationObserver` also works -- if you use it properly, which wasn't done here.  So while the OP thinks he has a solution, this answer currently will not help others with the same problem.